# How to Hide and Unhine rows using dollar figures using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My apologies if my question is too basic. I am trying to achieve the following results

1. If Cell E11 value is less than 25,000, then hide Rows 14 & 15.
2. If Cell E11 value is between 25k-50k, then hide only row 15 only.
3. If Cell E11 value is between 50k-75k, then unhide both rows.

And it is possible to make the calculation automated?

So far I found the following code, which of course isn't helping with my situation.

```
Sub PG1()

    If Range("E11").Value = "Pass" Then
        Rows("14:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E11").Value = "Fail" Then
        Rows("14:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why didn't you study the code you found?

Comment: I just started learning about the VBA world. Only if I could study the code.

Comment: lol I don't think you understand what study means XD

Comment: You can study the code, simply by reading it. I don't program in VBA either, and 2 minutes of studying the code was enough to figure out what it was doing and make changes to it. Most of that two minutes was waiting for Excel to load and open the VBA editor.  You have to at least make an effort to figure things out for yourself.

Comment: Hilarious. Love the sarcasm folks. Very motivational.

Answer (score 1):

A minor amount of trial and error based on nothing else but the code you posted gave me this code, which should get you started. It completes two of the three requirements (using different cells and rows), but it works. If it's still not something you can use to complete your task, you should probably hire someone to do this for you.

```
Sub ShowOrHide()
  If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value < 25000 Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value >= 50000 Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ken White. Much appreciate your quick response. Is there a way to add three triggers? In the above mentioned code, three two triggers, <25k and >=50k. If we can add just one more, that will do the trick. 1) <25k, 2) <50k, and 3) <75K. Is it possible?

Comment: I've done the majority of the work. Of course there's a way to add the third; it's another if block that adds the third condition. I've shown you exactly what you needed to do (starting with code that should have enabled you to do it yourself in the first place), and now you want me to do the extremely simple third part for you as well? This is not a hand-holding site. I've given you the necessary information to solve your problem, and done the majority of the work for you. Finishing it yourself will be educational.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. You didn't show me exactly what I needed and I am not sure what part of question's first statement you didn't get. No one asked you to hold hands. If you don't like the question, please don't respond back in an insulting manner. I forgot why I hated programming so much.

Comment: @AKP: You can't figure out how to add one more `ELSEIF` with a test for a value greater than one amount and less than another? This isn't a code writing service. You should learn to read answers here and then extend them to fit your specific requirements. There was no insulting manner - it was a statement that I'd given you everything you need **to figure out the rest yourself** instead of expecting someone to do it for you. Remember the old adage:*Give a man a fish and you feed him a meal; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*? Learn to fish instead of being spoon-fed a meal.

Comment: @ Ken White, on March 4th, I posted the answer to my own question. I wish you read the answer to my question first before posting your re-re-response on March 5th, but rather, you went on a lecture tour. I did figure out the rest myself. I have to say, this whole experience, specially your comments, is not a pleasant one.

Comment: @AKP: Yes, I saw your *own answer*, which was a copy of mine (badly formatted) with one line added. You didn't even have the courtesy to accept mine for leading you there. I have to say my whole experience with you, especially your lack of appreciation, has not been a pleasant one. Rest assured I won't waste my time helping you in the future as a result. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$E$11" Then

If Target.Value < 25000 Then Rows("13:15").EntireRow.Hidden = True

If Target.Value > 25000 Then Rows("13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Target.Value > 50000 Then Rows("13:15").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Target.Value > 75000 Then Rows("13:15").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub